# my script is not repeating itself for all div with same name

Tags: jquery

I have this script to run to replace names with icons , it works fine , but there are certain tables that are duplicated on the site and the script will replace the first instance of that table id , but not the other instance(s). How can i achieve that ?

```
(function($) {
  var prop, icontable = {}, $brief_standings, brief_standings_html, $livescoring_summary, livescoring_summary_html, team_name, img;

  for(prop in window.franchiseDatabase) {
    if (/^fid_/.test(prop) && prop !== 'fid_0000') {
      icontable[window.franchiseDatabase[prop].name] = window.franchiseDatabase[prop].icon;
    }
  }

  $brief_standings = $('#brief_standings');
  $livescoring_summary = $('#livescoring_summary');
  brief_standings_html = $brief_standings.html();
  livescoring_summary_html = $livescoring_summary.html();

  for (team_name in icontable) {
    if (icontable.hasOwnProperty(team_name)) {
      img = '<img src="' + icontable[team_name] + '" class="franchiseicon" />';
      if (brief_standings_html) {
        brief_standings_html = brief_standings_html.replace(team_name, img);
      }
      if (livescoring_summary_html) {
        livescoring_summary_html = livescoring_summary_html.replace(team_name, img);
      }
    }
  }

  $brief_standings.html(brief_standings_html);
  $livescoring_summary.html(livescoring_summary_html);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: first of all ids must be unique, use class instead

Comment: i dont have access to change the HTML

Comment: having duplicated ids is violating the rules of HTML coding, so you better work on something else, because it can not and should not be done!

Comment: its not a duplicate ID , rather a copied version of the same table , that displays in another area of the site

Comment: could you share your HTML as well please?

Comment: another problem I found is that you've defined `icontable` as `icontable = {}` which must be `icontable = []`

Comment: Good catch Amin ;) thanks - i'll set up a jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle too much html - here is link to demo site - i'm replacing the names with icons on this page - i have 1 table set in sprytabs and duplicate of same table stand alone - its populating 1st instance http://www20.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/74656

Comment: Live Scoring tab - icons display , Live Scoring stand alone table , do not display , if i flip the order , the first instance works in either case

Comment: it is a duplicated id as I suspected, both have the id `livescoring_summary`

Comment: so no way around it ?

Comment: what about using jquery to add a class to those ID's then making the script just work for the class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$brief_standings = $('*#brief_standings');
```

by inserting the asterix , it allows me to run the script on duplicated ID's